# How insert UTF8 when use Unique column in a table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, unique

i have error when try insert Vietnames in table have use field unique.
exam: 'tệ' and 'tê' are two word different. but Unique understand two word is one.

`INSERT INTO` keywords`(` Keyword`) VALUES ('tệ')`

> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'tệ' for key 'Keyword'

Comment: What is the collation of your table?

Comment: You probably need a binary collation for your field, such as utf8_bin or a Vietnamese specific one that distinguishes between these characters. See answers on accent sensitive questions